Нужна ли запятая после "ведь" в данном предложении?
Соберите за столом всех своих родных и друзей, ведь(?) как встретишь Новый год, так его и проведешь!

Можно использовать тире или оставить запятую:
Соберите за столом всех своих родных и друзей — ведь как встретишь Новый год, так его и проведешь!
Пояснение
Сложное предложение, три предикативные основы, два блока. Между блоками причинно-следственные отношения, обозначены тире (запятой).
Частица ведь используется в значении присоединительного союза. Запятая после частицы перед союзом КАК не ставится по правилу Розенталя.
 ВЕДЬ. I. частица. Употр. для усиления основного содержания 
 всего высказывания (предположения, утверждения, вопроса и 
 т.п.) или выделения, подчёркивания отдельного слова. В. 
 приди я вовремя, этого бы не случилось. В. поступи я иначе, 
 всё обошлось бы. Вы в. всё равно не пойдёте... И т. д.  
 II. союз. 1. Присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание 
 на причину, обоснование предыдущего высказывания. 
 Полагаемся на тебя, ты в. один знаешь дорогу. Пора домой, 
 в. уже поздно. 2. Несмотря на то, что; хотя. В. и сил нет, 
 а работаешь. В. говорил вам, да не послушались.

Розенталь § 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения.
 6. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные 
 частицы как раз, только, лишь, исключительно и т. п., то 
 перед ними ставится запятая (вопреки интонации, так как при 
 чтении пауза перед ними не делается): Катя вышла из 
 столовой, как раз когда мы шагнули друг к другу через 
 какие-то чемоданы (Кав.); Я эту работу выполню, только если 
 буду свободен (ср.: …если только буду свободен); 

